# SICP:'set' and 'define' in The Metacircular Evaluator

Tags: scheme, sicp

When evaluating and calling 'set-variable-value!' and 'define-variable-value!', the program will pass 'env' to the function, and in these two functions, 'set!' can only modify the 'env' which is inside the function; the modified 'env' is not returned as well.

So, how can the 'env' be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in the book, in section 3.3, [Modeling with Mutable Data](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html), mutable operators are introduced, by using the convention of suffixing the function name with `!`, like in `set-car!`, that modifies the car of a cons cell.

The functions `set-variable-value!` and `define-variable-value!` simply *modify* the passed environment, so that there is no need to return it. For instance, `set-variable-value!` is defined through the use of `set-car!`:

```
(define (set-variable-value! var val env)
  (define (env-loop env)
    (define (scan vars vals)
      (cond ((null? vars)
             (env-loop (enclosing-environment env)))
            ((eq? var (car vars))
             (set-car! vals val))
            (else (scan (cdr vars) (cdr vals)))))
    (if (eq? env the-empty-environment)
        (error "Unbound variable -- SET!" var)
        (let ((frame (first-frame env)))
          (scan (frame-variables frame)
                (frame-values frame)))))
  (env-loop env))
```

Note that the authors, at the beginning of [Chapter 4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-25.html), say:

> The language implemented by our evaluator will be a subset of the Scheme dialect of Lisp that we use in this book.

And since the dialect introduced has side-effects, the simplest solution to implement it is to use side-effects also in its interpreter.

Comment: I am sooo sorry, but I still don't get it:  When 'env' is passed to these two functions, I really think it is a copy(value) of 'env' that is passed, not the original 'env' itself. So it is the copy that is modified, but the original one is still unchanged. And there are three variables called 'env', I think that  what 'set-car!' modifies is the one of the parameters of the 'env-loop'.

Comment: @EndKin ,  in Scheme lists are passed by reference, not by copy, so the modifications are visible from the outside of the function.

Comment: @EndKin: It is copied. But the value `env` holds is a pointer to a pair structure, so by copying it you have two pointers to the same underlying structure, and changes to the structure made using one pointer will be seen through the other pointer. You can think of all values in Scheme being pointers to things, just like in, say, Python.

Comment: @Renzo: There is only pass-by-value in Scheme.

Comment: @newacct, yes, I now. I was saying, in a perhaps too synthetic and possibly misleading way, that if one think of a list as a value, which can be natural in a high level language, *that* value (the list) is not copied, but the reference to it is copied (i.e. is passed). I think that the idea of passing a whole structure as a value, by copy, is a thing that confuses many people,  not the last because "passing structures by copying the entire structure" is present in many modern languages. I agree that, in general, one should be more precise.

Comment: I am sorry, but i got confused again: are all the values passed in the form of pointer?

Comment: @EndKin, atomic values (symbols and numbers) are passed by copy; structures (i.e. lists, arrays) are passed by reference.